# Enqueue styles properly in a child theme and stylesheets location

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I have inherited a site without a child theme and now we will have problems when it comes to update things. Everything in this theme was made on the main theme...

I have now created a child theme but I have to enqueue a lot of scripts and stylesheets and I'm not doing it correctly. The main issue is, I have these custom stylesheets in a css folder in my child theme directory. But the functions look for these files on the parent theme so it doesn't find them obviously. Should I upload a custom stylesheet on the parent css directory? Or have it on my child theme directory and enqueue it differently?

Here's how my functions.php on my child theme look:

```
function shopkeeper_styles_child() {

    global $shopkeeper_theme_options;

    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-foundation-app', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/app.css', array(), '5.3.1', 'all' );     

    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css', array(), '2.0', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.0.3', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-arrows', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/arrows/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-basic', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/basic/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-basic_elaboration', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/basic_elaboration/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-ecommerce', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/ecommerce/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-music', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/music/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-software', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/software/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font-linea-weather', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/fonts/linea-fonts/weather/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );  
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-fresco', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fresco/fresco.css', array(), '1.3.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-idangerous-swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/idangerous.swiper.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css', array(), '1.3.1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-owl-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css', array(), '1.3.1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-offcanvas', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/offcanvas.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-nanoscroller', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/nanoscroller.css', array(), '0.7.6', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-select2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/select2.css', array(), '3.4.5', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-easyzoom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/easyzoom.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-defaults', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/defaults.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-woocommerce-overwrite', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/woocommerce-overwrite.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-top-bar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header-topbar.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-headers', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/headers.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-menus', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/navigations.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/shoopkeeper-child/css/custom_artiq.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

    if ( isset($shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_layout']) ) {     
        if ( $shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_layout'] == "1" ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-header-default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header-default.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        }       
        elseif ( $shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_layout'] == "2" ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-header-centered-2menus', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header-centered-2menus.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        }
        elseif ( $shopkeeper_theme_options['main_header_layout'] == "3" ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-header-centered-menu-under', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header-centered-menu-under.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        }       
    }       
    else {  
        wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-header-default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header-default.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );    
    }

    if (isset($shopkeeper_theme_options['font_source']) && ($shopkeeper_theme_options['font_source'] == "2")) {
        if ( (isset($shopkeeper_theme_options['font_google_code'])) && ($shopkeeper_theme_options['font_google_code'] != "") ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-font_google_code', $shopkeeper_theme_options['font_google_code'], array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        }
    }

    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_style('shopkeeper-default-style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shopkeeper_styles_child', 99 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `wp_enqueue_style( 'test', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/test.css' );`

instead of `get_template_directory_uri();`